# What does this Python expression mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Please advice, what does this expression return?

```
localized_title = lambda **_: localization._create_localized_string(0xB30B3A74)
```

What value will be stored in `localized_title` and what does

```
lambda **_:
```

mean?

Comment: For what it is worth, this is not a `lambda` use-case, and a full function definition should be used here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`**_` is a [kwargs glob](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/function.html). Any keyword arguments passed to the lambda will be stored in the dictionary `_`.

`_` is probably used a placeholder variable name, since the lambda expression doesn't use the arguments for anything.

`localized_title` will contain the lambda, i.e. a functional expression that can be called with arbitrary keyword arguments (which will be ignored) and which will return the return value of `localization._create_localized_string(0xB30B3A74)` at the time the lambda is invoked.

So `localized_title` is basically a wrapper around `localization._create_localized_string(0xB30B3A74)` that ignores all keyword arguments.